# How to set default options in datepicker()

Tags: jquery

How can you set some default options in datepicker() instead of setting the options each time the picker is initialized ?

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the [.setDefaults()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/setDefaults)

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( settings )
```

afterwards go just

```
$(".selector").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var defaultFormat = {dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'};
$.datepicker.setDefaults(defaultFormat);
```

Comment: is looking for a "better" solution